# Compair two file from DATAbase and if same move to another folder using UNIX script

Tags: database, shell, unix

I want to make a UNIX SCRIPt which compares TWO files in diffent path and if files are same move the file in anther folder (COMMON) and delete the two files after moving.

Comment: How is a database involved?

Comment: i have to connect to database and the do the process,but its  of if u can hellp me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

if diff /path1/file1 /path2/file2 >/dev/null ; then
  echo Same
  mv /path1/file1 /COMMON/file1
  rm /path2/file2
else
  echo Different
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh

cmp -s /path1/file1 /path2/file2 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  echo Different
else
  echo Same
  mv /path1/file1 /COMMON/file1
  rm /path2/file2
fi
```

Comment: Maybe consider only removing the files if the `mv` works successfully... `mv ... && rm ...`.

Comment: Wht we are using >dev/null ?

Comment: > means create file, /dev/null is  special file (device) it consumes all input sent to it